# Progressive download standard

Tags: http, client, standards, progressive-download

Is there any document which talks about how progressive download works. I am aware it is based on HTTP but need more information as to how the data is downloaded and what kind of messages flows between the player and the HTTP server. 
Is there any standard defined for the same.

Answer (score 3):

[This document](http://www.w3.org/2010/11/web-and-tv/papers/webtv2_submission_64.pdf) is the best I could find relating to standards for HTTP progressive downloads.

Another approach to this is [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) which is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

The document attached above talks about the Dynamic Adaptive Streaming. HTTP progressive download is completely different technique than adaptive streaming, in the sense that it is NOT adaptive.

In progressive download, the video (or content) file is downloaded as if just another download happens over HTTP.